# Need to loop through directory - delete lines that match pattern

Tags: perl

Need to loop through a Unix directory and search each line in each file. If there is a pattern match delete the line.  Was not able to get the line deletion to work so i'm just trying to find pattern and replace with another.

Populating an array with file names and looping through.  I have a counter set it's looking at each of the lines in each file (at least they count is correct).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -w
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

# 4-1-19
# pfs
# remove lines with dental code ADD2999 from all HMO Max load files in /home/hsxxx/dat/feeLoad directory

$| = 1;


chdir "/home/hstrn/dat/feeLoad";
chdir;


my $dir  = </home/hstrn/dat/feeLoad/>;
my @files;
my $count=0;

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open directory $dir, Perl says $!\n";

while (my $file = readdir DIR)
{
        push @files, "$dir/$file" unless -d "$dir/$file";
}

closedir DIR;

{
local @ARGV = @files;
while (<>)
{
        s/ADD2999/sometext/g;
        $count++;
}
print "Total lines read are: $count";

}
```

Would expect all strings ADD2999 to be replaced with sometext

Comment: "_expect all strings ADD2999 to be replaced_"  -- you are replacing them, but in a variable in your program (the `$_` variable); that's never written to a file.  In order to change text in a file you generally need to rewrite the whole file.  So, iterate over `@files`, and as you read each line of a file write it over to another file (change what needs changing), and when that's all done move that other file over the original.  (_Test carefully first_, before you change all your files!)   Do you know how to do this?

Comment: The above can be simplified by using modules. In particular, [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) has a method ([edit_lines](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw)) that will make a change to a file (it does all the above behind the scenes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove lines, you need to avoid printing them when writing to the new file. Your code doesn't write to any files at all???

---

This might be a job for existing tools.

```
find /home/hstrn/dat/feeLoad -maxdepth 1 -type f \
   -exec perl -i~ -ne'print if !/ADD2999/' {} +
```

Use `-i` instead of `-i~` if you want to avoid creating a backup. I prefer creating the backups, then deleting them once I've confirmed that everything is ok.

Show the files that are going to get deleted:

```
find /home/hstrn/dat/feeLoad -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*~'
```

Delete the files:

```
find /home/hstrn/dat/feeLoad -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*~' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my first attempt at the problem, but it could use some more corner case checking. E.g. how do you handle write-protected files, etc. It also assumes that the files are small enough to fit into memory for processing.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

use File::Spec;
use File::Slurper qw(read_text write_text);

my $count = 0;
my $dir = "tmp";

opendir(my $dh, $dir);
while (readdir $dh) {
    # skip anything that shouldn't be processed
    next if /^\.\.?$/; # . && ..
    my $file = File::Spec->catfile($dir, $_);
    next if -d $file;  # directories

    # slurp file content and replace text
    my $content = read_text($file);
    my $matches = ($content =~ s/ADD2999/sometext/g);

    # count lines
    my @eols = ($content =~ /(\n)/g);
    $count += @eols;

    # replace original file if contents were modified
    write_text($file, $content) if $matches;
}
closedir($dh);

print "Total lines read are: $count\n";

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ wc -l tmp/test*.txt
  5 tmp/test2.txt
  6 tmp/test.txt
 11 total
$ fgrep ADD2999 tmp/*.txt
tmp/test2.txt:asddsada ADD2999 asdsadasd
tmp/test2.txt:21312398 ADD2999 dasdas

$ perl dummy.pl
Total lines read are: 11

$ fgrep ADD2999 tmp/*.txt
$ fgrep sometext tmp/*.txt
tmp/test2.txt:asddsada sometext asdsadasd
tmp/test2.txt:21312398 sometext dasdas
```

If the files are large you will need to use line-by-line processing approach (just showing the contents of the loop). That has the side-effect that all files will be touched, although they might not have any replacements in it:

```perl
# read file and replace text
open(my $ifh, '<', $file);
my $tmpfile = File::Spec->catfile($dir, "$_.$$");
open(my $ofh, '>', $tmpfile);
while (<$ifh>) {
    s/ADD2999/sometext/g;
    print $ofh $_;
}
$count += $.; # total lines in $ifh
close($ofh);
close($ifh);

# replace original file with new file
unlink($file);
rename($tmpfile, $file);
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan that worked perfectly at home using Linux.  Unfortunately at work we do not have the File::Slurper module installed.